If $f(x)\sim g(x)$, is $f'(x)\sim g'(x)$ for $f,g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$?

Consider a complex-valued function $f(\sigma+it)$ which satisfies $$f(\sigma+it)\sim g(\sigma+it),$$ as $|t|\to\infty.$ Must it be the case that $f'(\sigma+it)\sim g'(\sigma+it)$?

Consider, for example, $$f(\sigma+it)\sim\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)^{1-c-it}e^{it+i\frac{\pi}{4}};$$ this is actually a result due to Stirling's approximation for the $\chi$ factor of the Riemann zeta functional equation! But if one wants to find an asymptotic for $f'(\sigma+it)$, are they permitted to just differentiate this above asymptotic for $f(\sigma+it)$?
Of course if this were an equality things would be much more straightforward and we could differentiate if we were so inclined, but since we have an error term with an asymptotic it's not obvious to me that this is legitimate.
On the other hand, if we have two functions being asymptotic to each other, they have the same growth rate asymptotically so it is natural to expect their derivatives to be asymptotically equivalent?

You should clarify which variable tends to infinity (or other value) when using the $\sim$ notation.

This is generally not true: Take for instance $f(t) = t + \sin(t^2)/t$ and $g(t)=t$. Then certainly $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=1$ but the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}$ doesn't exist.

@jjagmath added into the question -- $|t|\to\infty$. Thanks for pointing this out!

@frog nice counterexample -- do you know if there are any conditions one could impose on a function to guarantee $f'=g'$?

In your question $\sigma$ does not change, so it is a single-variable problem: when $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are differentiable in $t$ and $A(t) \sim B(t)$ as $|t| \to \infty$, you want to know whether $A'(t) \sim B'(t)$. A simple counterexample is $A(t) = t + \sin t$ and $B(t) = t$.
Here is an example where differentiation on both sides in an asymptotic relation as $t \to \infty$ is valid, with the right side being a particular function. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbf R$ and satisfies $a \leq b \Longrightarrow f'(a) \leq f'(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$. If $f(t) \sim t^c$ for a positive constant $c$, then $f'(t) \sim ct^{c-1}$. (Hint: Use the Newton quotient $(f((1 + \varepsilon)t) - f(t))/(\varepsilon t)$ as an approximation to $f'(t)$ and get upper and lower bounds on that quotient by the Mean Value Theorem. Then divide by $t^{c-1}$, let $t \rightarrow \infty$, and let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$.)
